# How can I implement a data migration with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, data-migration

I'm supposed to move data from an old server to a new one while changing the structure.

Example:

- old: "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\companyA\200031_Signs"
- new: "C:\test\new\Data\06. Aufträge\companyA\200031_companyA_Signs"

In the old structure, the orders of a company are in a single folder.
In the new structure, all orders are to be migrated directly under the orders folder. The name consists of the order number + separator + company name + name.

current task is the folders that were successfully copied from "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\%company%\" in the folder "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\%company%\Z_Transfered" to move.

I tried:

```
$sourcepath = "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge"
$basepath = "C:\test\new\Data\06. Aufträge"


$Orders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1
ForEach ($Order in $Orders ) {
if  ($Order.name.StartsWith("20")){
    $NewFolderName = "{0}\{1}" -f ($BasePath),($order.Name.insert(6,"_" + $order.parent.Name))
    $NewFolder = New-Item -Path $NewFolderName -ItemType "directory"
    Copy-Item -Path "$($Order.FullName)\*" -Destination $NewFolder -Recurse -Force

#under construction
    $MoveFolderName = Join-Path -path $sourcepath -ChildPath $order.parent | Join-Path -ChildPath "Z_Transfered"
    if (-not (Test-Path $MoveFolderName))
     {
     New-Item -Path  $MoveFolderName -ItemType "directory"
     }
    $MoveFolder = $MoveFolderName +"\" + $order.name
    Move-Item -Path "$($Order.FullName)\*" -Destination $MoveFolder
    $error > $sourcepath"\error.log"
}
```

}

I adapted the code I got yesterday. Currently I have one more error in the code.

Copy content to the right place works now.
Currently he creates the folder Z_Transfered below the customer folder. The problem seems to be with Move-Item.
Currently, the folder is not moved to Z_Transfered, only the files under the customer folder are moved and, unfortunately, also renamed. Can someone help me here please?

Comment: are there other folders inside the order folder (inside 20031_Signs)?

Comment: in these and most other cases yes

Comment: is Powershell 5 available?

Comment: yes is available

Comment: The sample code you posted would sort-of re-create the childfolders from `$sourcepath` (which won't work correctly since object properties are not expanded inside strings). It doesn't even attempt to produce the desired new names. Please try a little harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the parentfolder of a folder by putting `.parent` to the pathobject > `$path.parent`. And you can even get the grandparent that way > `$path.parent.parent`.
So all that is left is a little string manipulation to get the new folder name:

```
$sourcepath = "d:\test\Data\Orders"    # Adjust this
$BasePath = "d:\test\Data\Orders"    # Adjust this

$Orders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 2
ForEach ($Order in $Orders ) {

    if ( $Order.parent.parent.Name -eq "Orders" ){
        $NewFolderName = "{0}\{1}" -f ($BasePath),($order.Name.replace("_","_$($Order.parent)_"))
        $NewFolder = New-Item -Path $NewFolderName -ItemType "directory"
        Move-Item -Path "$($Order.FullName)\*" -Destination $NewFolder -WhatIf
    }
}
```

In Powershell 5 `Get-ChildItem` got the `-Depth` parameter so you can limit it to search only two levels below your `$sourcepath`. The replace will look for `_` in the foldername so make sure thery all contain only one.

Comment: I have adjusted the variables. Instead of Move-Item I used Copy-Item. In my test, not all files are copied, what can be the case? Is it also possible if in the folder name several "_" are available? The problem is that there are several thousand folders. Some folders use as a sign also a "-". Unfortunately, the current structure is not uniform.

Comment: The way it is now every `_` in the Order-foldername will be replaced by `"_$($Order.parent)_"` > multiple is not good :). If you have other seperators, you could just add them to be replaced `($order.Name.replace("_","_$($Order.parent)_").replace("-","_$($Order.parent)_")` this however would replace all `_` AND `-`. The best soluten would be to create multiple `if` statements to check which company the order belongs to and to choose based on that what kinde of replace you will use...

Comment: for the problem with `copy-item` not copying everything try `-force` (maybe with admin rights)

Comment: `copy-item` works with the parameters `-recurse` and `-force`

Comment: is there also the possibility to work with two loops? one to read out the customer's name and a second one for each subfolder of the customer to create the new name and copy the files. Now only the folders are to be copied and renamed with "20" begin after the sixth character then the customer name with one to be inserted.

Comment: Of course you can nest as many loops and ifs as you want just make sure you are closing all the brakets correctly `if ($true) { foreach( $a in $b){ if ($true) { while ($c -le $d ) {copy-stuff } } } }`

Answer (score 0):

it works :)

many thanks for your help.
The script works now as I need it.

```
$sourcepath = "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge"
$basepath = "C:\test\new\Data\06. Aufträge"


$Orders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1
ForEach ($Order in $Orders ) {
if  ($Order.name.StartsWith("20")){
    $NewFolderName = "{0}\{1}" -f ($BasePath),($order.Name.insert(6,"_" + $order.parent.Name))
    $NewFolder = New-Item -Path $NewFolderName -ItemType "directory"
    Copy-Item -Path "$($Order.FullName)\*" -Destination $NewFolder -Recurse -Force
    $MoveFolderName = Join-Path -path $sourcepath -ChildPath $order.parent | Join-Path -ChildPath "Z_Transfered"
     if (-not (Test-Path $MoveFolderName))
       {
        $MoveFolder = New-Item -Path  $MoveFolderName -ItemType "directory"
       }
    Move-Item -path "$($Order.FullName)\" -Destination $MoveFolderName -force
    $error > $sourcepath"\error.log"
 }
}
```